# Как сделать выборку с условием?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Привет.

Есть 3 таблицы

- param(id, name)
- paramValue(id, paramId, value)
- paramValueCode(id, paramId, value, localizationKey)

Если `paramValue.Value = paramValueCode.Value`, то выбираем `paramValueCode.localizationKey` иначе `paramValue.Value`. На выходе нужно:

```
param, value, isLocalizationKey
```

Заранее спасибо.

**Разобрался**

```
select 
    case when t.localizationKey is null
    then t.value
    else t.localizationKey
    end as value,
case when t.localizationKey is null
    then 0
    else 1
    end as isLocalizationKey

from(
    select pv.value, 
    (select localizationKey from ParamValueCode pvc where pvc.value = pv.value and              pvk.paramId = pv.paramId) as localizationKey
from param p join paramValue pv on p.id = pv.paramId) t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name as param, 
case when paramValue.Value = paramValueCode.Value 
then paramValueCode.localizationKey else paramValue.Value end as value, LocalizationKey
from param join paramValue on param.id = paramValue.paramid
join paramValueCode on param.id = paramValueCode.paramid
```

[case](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html)